# How does glGenerateMipmap work in OpenGL? The filter seems not work

Tags: opengl

I use `glGenerateMipmap()` in OpenGL to generate some mipmaps after setting the parameter by `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST)` and `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)`, respectively.
Then I access the mipmaps of level 2 by `glGetTexImage()` twice. The results seems with no difference.
So I wonder how `glGenerateMipmap()` works and how to apply the different filter modes on it, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filtering parameters do not (or at least, the standard does not require them to) affect the output of `glGenerateMipMaps`. It will generate mipmaps based on an implementation-defined algorithm, not based on your filtering parameters.

Comment: oh, it sounds terrible! So you mean the filtering algorithm can't be changed by users, right?

Comment: @xawthunder: It's a simple tool for simple needs. The most common case is to use a box filter. If you need something more specific, you have all the tools available to you (FBOs, compute shaders, etc) to build something more complicated or even something simpler.

Comment: That helps a lot. I may try compute shader, although it's a challenge for me. Thank you.